# Sass ampersand when base uses pseudo-element (before / after)

Tags: css, sass

I have multiples `div::before` that share 90% of the styling and I want to style them using the nested structure of SASS to only specify the differences after while keeping them grouped. But I can't found how to do it when the base that will become the `&` is already using a pseudo-element. When doing this :

**SASS**

```
#home .foo .bar::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2px;
    background: url("images/baz.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 39px;
    width: 56px;

    &.item-1 {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }        
    &.item-2 {
        top: 10px;
        right: 20px;
    }
    &.item-3 {
        top: 40px;
        right: 60px;
    }
    ...
}
```

**OUTPUT CSS**

```
#home .foo .bar::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2px;
    background: url("images/baz.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 39px;
    width: 56px;

#home .foo .bar::before.item-1 {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}        
#home .foo .bar::before.item-2 {
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}
#home .foo .bar::before.item-3 {
    top: 40px;
    right: 60px;
}
...
```

Of course the problem is that the ampersand takes the whole root with the `::before` and add the class `.item-x` at the end of this so the css rule doesn't work. My desired output is `#home .foo .bar.item-2::before`. I'm not even sure that it's possible to nest that way so any help would be nice.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is your best bet:

```
#home .foo .bar {
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2px;
    background: url("images/baz.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 39px;
    width: 56px;
  }

  &.item-1 {
    &:before {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  }

  …
}
```

Demo: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d2d89f0d7070a3473a6c

You could also write as `&.item-1:before {…}` if you prefer.

Comment: Simple, Neat and smart

Comment: Yes I think it's the best/simple option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`@at-root` might be useful here to keep the styles grouped whilst controlling what the root is. Take a look at this:

```
#home .foo .bar::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2px;
    background: url("images/baz.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 39px;
    width: 56px;

  @at-root #home .foo .bar.item1::before {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  @at-root #home .foo .bar.item2::before {
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
  }

  @at-root #home .foo .bar.item2::before {
    top: 40px;
    right: 60px;
  }
}
```

**Outputs as:**

```
#home .foo .bar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  background: url("images/baz.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 39px;
  width: 56px;
}
#home .foo .bar.item1::before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#home .foo .bar.item2::before {
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}
#home .foo .bar.item2::before {
  top: 40px;
  right: 60px;
}
```